# Has the bottom port of the Wii U Gamepad been used for something?

Tags: wii-u

The Wii U has a port between the two charge terminals on the bottom of the controller. Has this port been ever used for something? (like official or 3rd party accessories or modifications)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/wiiu/comments/9t5m0q/bottom_port_on_gamepad/) claims:

> It's an accessory connector/port that was never used. With the Wii U doing so badly in sales, Nintendo and third parties never made any accessories for the Wii U gamepad. This picture shows how it could have been used.

The post includes a link to a picture that shows something like a joystick accessory connecting to this port (which never went to market):

[image: joystick]

The [official Nintendo User Guide](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/downloads/manual-nintendo-wiiu-operations-english.pdf) calls this port an Accessory Connector, and multiple sources claim the same.  Because of the unpopularity of the product, no accessories were ever made to utilize this slot (none that I could find at least).

[image: guide image]

Comment: I was expecting a 3rd party mod like the [Gameshark and PSIO for the unused Parallel I/O port on the PS1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/377446/199843) (I had already seen the Reddit post before posting the question). I guess that there are no mods using this port (for now at least).